# On vercel, How can I disable rewrites?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am making a website with vite and typescript, where it has to have paths like /users/bob or /users/alice. I have looked all over their documentation but I cannot find anything on how to disable these. Does someone know how to do this? Thanks!

ALSO:
I don't care if it makes the invalid file found error, I have a check w/ react-router-dom for that.